# Custom doctrine configuration per environment

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

Is it possible to have the API use a different doctrine.yaml file per environment?

I am able to edit the stock file in api/config/doctrine.yaml.
But what if I want to use a different database for test or production environments?

I see a config/packages/test and config/packages/prod folder with other yaml config files but adding a doctrine file to those folders doesn't seem to override the top level doctrine.yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest version of API Platform:

1. Create a `api/.env.test` file (you can replace the final suffix by the name of your env it is not `test`)
2. Override the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable for this specific environment: `DATABASE_URL=postgres://my-user:my-password@the-db-host/my-test-db`

To check if you use the latest version of the `.env` file system, and for more information about environment variables in Symfony and API Platform, read https://symfony.com/blog/improvements-to-the-handling-of-env-files-for-all-symfony-versions